# Resource is busy, but lsof doesn't think so

Tags: macos, terminal, filesystem

Occasionally, I get file (typically after they are edited by Microsoft Word) that I can not delete:

```
> rm -rf foo.docx
rm: M_AI_SO.docx: Resource busy
```

However, `lsof` doesn't report anything, even I run it as root:

```
> lsof | grep docx
>
```

How can I determine who is locking the file. And even more important: how can I delete it without a reboot?

Answer (score 1):

`lsof` does not show all the processes when run as a *normal* user. Try with

```
sudo lsof | grep docx
```

See the [`SECURITY` section of the man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/lsof.8.html)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, but I did so. I'll edit the question.